# Promise then() executed before resolve is called inside a nested promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nodemailer

The purpose of the code below is to perform sending emails from my Node application. The issue I am running into is the `check()` promise is 'finishing' w/o resolve/reject being called.

**Context**

*This is purely for context, skip if you want to see the problem area*

The execution is as follows:
`POST -> perform DB inserts -> send Email`

Send Email consists of:

`sendRegistrationEmail -> (start email send proc) Check STMP ready -> Send Email -> finished`

I am calling [transporter.verify()](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/) to ensure the SMTP server is ready.

> You can verify your SMTP configuration with verify(callback) call
> (also works as a Promise).

I have also broken up the call to `verify()`, it does infact return a promise

**Problem:**

Upon calling the following method (in a promise form), it skips the `reject()`/`resolve()` completely as if it weren't there.

In both method 1 & 2, the `verify()` is infact invoked and does return a result, however it is not 'inline' with the promise.

```
const check = (transporter) => {

// Method 1
    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //     let c = transporter               // executed
    //     const promise = c.verify();       // executed - promise is infact a promise object here
    //     return promise.then(() => {       // line hit & returns i.e. nothing happens further
    //         console.log("Connection to SMTP successful, ready to send");     // after a while, the promise resolves, at this point, the POST has already responded i.e. the resolve() plays no part
    //         resolve(transporter);
    //     }).catch(reason => {
    //         console.log(`Cannot send email. Error: ${reason}`)                // this is also hit later, but once again after POST has responded
    //         reject(reason);
    //     })
    // });

// Method 2
    return transporter.verify().then(() => {     // line run, then 'exits'
        console.log("Connection to SMTP successful, ready to send");     // later this line is hit after POST has responded.
        return transporter
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(`Cannot send email. Error: ${reason}`);              // this is also hit later, but once again after POST has responded
        throw reason;
    })
}
```

called with `promise.then(check).then()...catch()`

How can I call `check()` in the form mentioned above and have the `resolve()` / `reject()` return a result and the next `then()` responding on that `resolve()` or `catch()` on `reject()`?

**code stack**

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "domain.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "user",
        pass: "pass"
    }
});

const check = (transporter) => {

// Method 1
    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //     let c = transporter
    //     const promise = c.verify();
    //     return promise.then(() => {
    //         console.log("Connection to SMTP successful, ready to send");
    //         resolve(transporter);
    //     }).catch(reason => {
    //         console.log(`Cannot send email. Error: ${reason}`)
    //         reject(reason);
    //     })
    // });

// Method 2
    return transporter.verify().then(() => {
        console.log("Connection to SMTP successful, ready to send");
        return transporter
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(`Cannot send email. Error: ${reason}`);
        throw reason;
    })
}

const send = ({to, from, subject, body, bodyText}) => {
    new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("= Sending Email =");
        console.log(`\tTo:\t\t${to}`);
        console.log(`\tFrom:\t\t${from}`);
        console.log(`\tSubject:\t${subject}`);
        console.log(`\tContent:\t${body}`);
        console.log(`\tContent Text:\t${bodyText}`);
        resolve(transporter);
    }).then(check).then(transporter => {
        return transporter.sendMail({
            from: from,
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            text: bodyText,
            html: body
        })
    }).then(value => {
        console.log(`Sent message ID: ${value.messageId}`)
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(`Failed to send email. Error: ${reason}`);
    });
}

const sendRegistrationEmail = (email) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let from = "admin@mydomain.com";
        let subject = "Welcome"
        let body = "<b>Welcome</b> <h1>Launching Soon</h1>";
        let bodyText = "Welcome. Launching Soon";
        resolve({email, from, subject, body, bodyText});
    }).then(value => {
        return send(value);
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log("Email Send failed");
    })
}

module.exports = {
    sendRegistrationEmail: sendRegistrationEmail
};
```

Comment: Was "Connection to SMTP successful, ready to send" logged to the console? I don't think your code has any problem.

Comment: hi @DucNguyen infact no - it has an issue with 'getting first TLS certificate" if memory serves, however this is shown AFTER the post has returned to the user. So user will see all good while infact the sending of registration email has failed (due to reject/resolve) not be hit